# .htaccess and localhost issue

Tags: joomla-2.5, sef, .htaccess-configuration, redirect, localhost

Local dev environment Win10/XAMPP

I have a number of local websites in my htdocs folder (eg. MyTestSite) that I access by visiting `localhost/MyTestSite` these work fine.

So today I restored a (Joomla 2.5.6) site from a live environment to my local pc (htdocs/3i). I visited `localhost/3i` expecting to see my new website, but instead the address bar immediately changed to `http://www.localhost/xampp/` which took me to my Welcome to XAMPP for Windows! page.

Now if I type `www.localhost/3i` I can see my homepage, but none of the other links work, they take me straight back to `www.localhost/xampp/`

I assumed this had something to do with my .htaccess file (which is below) however I can't see anything that may be causing this, although I'm no htaccess expert!

Answer (score 1):

An .htaccess file from a live environment may contain many directives that cannot work in another environment, especially a localhost environment.

In your case, I would guess to look for the
`# RewriteBase /`, that according to your root directory `localhost/3i`, it should be:

`# RewriteBase /3i`.

#### update:

Actually, it needs to be uncommented like:  **`RewriteBase /3i`**, with no **`#`**.

Also I don't have experience with XAMPP for Windows, but it sounds a bit strange to me that you can reach your `localhost` using the `www` domain.
Review this particular .htaccess to see if there are any redirections of `non www` to `www`.

Check in htaccess for something like below, and comment it out:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Generally, if you can't make things work:**

- Disable **SEF** and **Rewrite** settings in **Joomla Global Configuration**
- Totally **remove** (or backup) current **.htaccess**, and simply use Joomla's default one - if this is needed in your current local setup.